# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in CodeIniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

In `CodeIgniter` I need to insert an appointment information. Now the problem's that each appointment could have more service associated. So for fix this I've think to create for one appointment multiple row, for example:

**Appointment details**

service: cut , color

How you can see there are two service associated, so in my database I'll have two row like this:

```
id|    name     | service
10  appointment    cut
10  appointment |  color
```

now instead of cut and color in my implementation there's a number, 'cause I've another table with all service details. This is my code that allow me to insert the appointment in my table:

```
$appuntamento = $appointment; 
unset($appuntamento['id_services']);

foreach($appointment['id_services'] as $id)
{
    $appuntamento['id_services'] = $id; 

      if(!$this->db->insert('ea_appointments', $appuntamento))
      {
          throw new Exception('Error.');
      }
      $insert_id = intval($this->db->insert_id());
}
return $insert_id;
```

In this function I pass the parameter `appointment`, I clone the `appointment` object in appuntamento object 'cause I need to loop through each service available in the `appointment`.

In fact should there be so many lines of the same date in table, as the number of services associated? I'm executing an unset of the `id_services` 'cause it's an array and as I said I need to insert the same appointment for each service associated.

So in the foreach I set the index `id_services` of my appuntamento variable. So I insert the object, the structure is like this:

```
INSERT INTO `ea_appointments` (`id_users_provider`, `start_datetime`, `end_datetime`, 
    `notes`, `is_unavailable`, `id_users_customer`, `book_datetime`, `hash`, `id_services`) 
VALUES ('85', '2015-11-14 22:00:00', '2015-11-14 22:00:00', '', 0, '87', 
    '2015-11-14 12:00:33', '7a7e195d47b22cfd795f1876b3d2711b', '15')
```

but I get this error:

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

In my database table I've unset the `auto_increment` 'cause if I set the auto_increment I'll get the same appointment information in multiple row with different id, and this is wrong.

In the last code line, anyway, I'm trying to return the id of inserted appointment.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this particular instance, it's better to create another table such as `appointment_services`, and then on that table have a `id | appointment_id | service_id`. This way you can query the table by appointment id, get join the services table on the service ids.

Comment: I've already this.. In my example I've wrotten the name of the service but in realty I insert the id.. The problem isn't this but the error pasted above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in my database table I've unsetted the auto_increment 'cause if I set
>   the auto_increment I'll get the same appointment information in
>   multiple row with different id, and this is wrong.

Try this: make your id auto increment. Then add a separate field to hold the appointment id.

Answer (score 0):

You have "Duplicate entry '0'" because you have not autoincrement for `ea_appointments.id`.

You can add autoincrement for `ea_appointments.id`.

And after insert you can use id of inserted record with `$this->db->insert_id()` (or for example, with [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php)) for inserting into associated table.

Comment: getlastInsertedId() is a method of CodeIgniter? I can't find it, could you show me an example please?

Comment: Method of PDO: lastInsertId instead of getLastInsertId(), http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: You using $this->db->insert_id() - it is equal

Comment: Okay but I must get the first auto_increment id inserted 'cause I need to assign the same id of the appointment for each duplicate row of all services associated.

Comment: Yes. Your steps will be next: 1. insert into appointments. 2. set app_id = get last inserted id. 3. insert into associated table 2 rows. one row with appointment_id = app_id and secont record with appointment_id = app_id too.

Comment: Uhm but if I remove the auto_increment and try to set the id through code? How can I do this without have possible duplicate of id?

Comment: You can use GUIDs instead of integer ids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95164/discussion-between-dillinger-and-mnv).

Answer (score 0):

make two master tables that are 
1> mstr_appointment : this table contains appointment details.
2> mstr_services : this contains details about different services.

then create 1 reference table 
**appointment_service :** this contain detail about which appointment include which services.

Ex:

1> mstr_appointment

- id_users_provider (primary key,auto increament)
- start_datetime
- end_datetime
- notes
- is_unavailable
- id_users_customer
- book_datetime
- hash
  2> mstr_services
- service_id (primary key,auto increament)
- service_name

3> appointment_service (reference table)
 - id (primary key,auto increament)
 - id_users_provider (foreign key=>mstr_appointment)
 - service_id (foreign key=>mstr_services)

[ex of 3 tables with dataentry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JqF3.jpg)
Writ insert query according to table design. only id of appointment and service need to be inserted.
While fetch record need to write simple join.
Simple...!!!